# I am designing a html page and i wanted to replace up-arrow and down-arrow to star and i (info).please suggest me in css

Tags: html, css, materialize

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" class="no-js">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8" />
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"> 
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 

            <meta name="description" content="" />
            <meta name="keywords" content="" />
            <meta name="author" content="" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="font/roboto/font.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="preloader/preloader.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="font/icons/ionicon/css/ionicons.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/base/materialize.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/green.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate/magic.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/base/test.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/base/post.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/base/jquery.scrollbar.css" />
    </head>


    <body>

                <!--?php include '../header.php'?-->
                <div id="bg-overlay"> </div>

            <div class="container-fluid" id="main" style="display: block;">
                <!--?php echo $fout ?-->
                <div class="row" id="content">
                    <div class="col s12">

                    </div>
                    <div class="post col l4 m6 s12">

                        <div class="col s6 offset-s3 post-image center no-padding" style="width: 202px; height: 202px; background: url(&quot;images/post/1.jpg&quot;) 0% 0% / 100% 100%;">
                            <div class="postdate" style="height: 202px; padding-top: 71px;"><span>23/6</span><br>12:00 am</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col s12 post-below no-padding waves-effect z-depth-3" style="margin-top: -71px;">
                            <label class="col s6 left no-padding">
                                <div id="up-vote"><i class="ion-arrow-up-c"></i> <label class="up-vote"></label></div>
                            </label>
                            <label class="col s6 right no-padding">
                                <div id="down-vote"><label class="down-vote"></label> <i class="ion-arrow-down-c"></i></div>
                            </label>
                            <div class="col s12 post-head center truncate" style="padding-top: 57.3333px;">
                                Game Title
                            </div>
                            <hr class="post-head-bottom">
                            <div class="col s12 desp">
                                <div class="post-detail "></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row" id="bottom-row">
                            <div class="col s7 left auth no-padding">


                            </div>
                            <div class="col s5 right right-align comment-contain">
                                                            <a href="#">Know more</a>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div><!-- /container -->






        <script src="js/post.js"></script>
        <script>    


            $(document).ready(function(){
                $.backstretch("images/back.png");

                if(newuser==1){
                    $("#content").css('display','none');
                }


            })




        </script>
    <div class="hiddendiv common"></div><div class="backstretch" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; overflow: hidden; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; height: 667px; width: 808px; z-index: -999999; position: fixed;"><img src="images/back.png" style="position: absolute; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: none; width: 998.005px; height: 667px; max-height: none; max-width: none; z-index: -999999; left: -95.0025px; top: 0px;"></div></body>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRb8N.jpg)

so when i click on star it should show me the ratings as it is shown in the left part of the image and when i click on info(i symbol) it should show me the gaming info as it is shown in the right part of the image.

```
/*css/base/post.css*/

    @keyframes fillup {
        from {width:0%}
        to {width:75%}
    }



    @media(max-width:992px){
        .comment-contain,.auth{padding-top:50px !important}
        .auth-name{font-size:16px !important}
    }
    @media(min-width:993px){    
        .comment-contain,.auth{padding-top:50px !important}
    }





    #content{color:#90a4ae;position: absolute;top:130px;right: 0;left: 0;}
    .post{margin-bottom:20px}
    /*  post image*/

    .post>div.post-image{background:#4fc3f7;border-radius:50%;z-index:2;position:relative;width:100%;background-position:center !important;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 14px 2px rgba(33,33,33,1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 14px 2px rgba(33,33,33,1);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 14px 2px rgba(33,33,33,1);
    transition:1s all ease;-webkit-transition:1s all ease;-moz-transition:1s all ease;-ms-transition:1s all ease;
    }
    .post>div.post-image:hover{background-size:150% 150% !important;cursor: pointer;}

    .postdate{font-size:20px;color:#fff;font-weight:700;background:rgba(21,21,21,0.5);border-radius:50%;opacity:0;text-align:center;
    transition:0.3s all ease;-webkit-transition:0.3s all ease;-moz-transition:0.3s all ease;-ms-transition:0.3s all ease;}
    .postdate>span{font-size:30px;font-weight:300}
    .post>div.post-image:hover .postdate{opacity:1}
    /* votes*/
    .vote{font-size:20px;color: #e0e0e0;}

    #up-vote,#down-vote{font-size:20px;color:#e0e0e0;line-height:35px;font-weight:300;margin-top:10px;
    transition:0.3s all ease-in;-webkit-transition:0.3s all ease-in;-moz-transition:0.3s all ease-in;-ms-transition:0.3s all ease-in;}

    #up-vote{margin-left:20px}
    #down-vote{text-align:right;margin-right:20px}
    .up-vote,.down-vote{font-size:20px;color:#e0e0e0}

    /* below*/
    .post-below{border:2px solid #e0e0e0;color:#e0e0e0;border-radius:5px;z-index:1;position:relative;}
    /*post date & time*/

    .post-head{font-size:25px;font-weight:500;}
    .post-head-bottom{float:left;animation:fillup 2s;-webkit-animation: fillup 2s;-moz-animation: fillup 2s;width:75%;height:2px;background:#fff}
    .post-detail{height:50px;}

    .comment-contain,.auth{padding-top:20px}
    .comment{border:2px solid #ffd54f ;padding:10px;font-weight:500;color:#e0e0e0;background:rgba(255,213,79,0.5);}

    .auth-img{width:40px;height:40px;border-radius:50%}
    .auth-name{color:#e0e0e0;font-size:18px;font-weight:300;line-height:40px}




I want to change the code in div id="up-vote" and div id="down-vote" in css to star and alphabet i which mean info.
I am unable to insert the star and letter i in the places of up-arrow and down-arrow.


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nN64m.jpg
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can understand, you just want to change the icons from arrows to stars. Looks like you don't need to change #up-vote or #down-vote, but you need to change the icons inside them and their attributes.

Change `<i class="ion-arrow-up-c"></i>` and `<i class="ion-arrow-down-c"></i>` to: `<i class="ion-star"></i>`

Comment: i also need info symbol on right side so what should i do.

Comment: `<i class="ion-information-circled"></i>` or `<i class="ion-information"></i>`
You can view the list of icons that you're using at http://ionicons.com/ to see what classes they are using.

Comment: when i click on star it should show me the ratings as it is shown in the left part of the image and when i click on info(i symbol) it should show me the gaming info as it is shown in the right part of the image.

Comment: please suggest me i need a quick reply.